# Help interpret geometry word problem.

Tags: geometry

I am having a hard time understanding this word problem: *A common tangent is drawn to two disks which have the distance d between centers, and the radii R and r. Compute the position of the intersection point of this tangent with the line of centers, when the point lies: (i) to one side of both centers, or (ii) between them*. There is no figure for this problem, but I made one up. Maybe you could point what "position" it wants me to compute. Note however that concept of Coordinates is not introduced yet.

[image]

Comment: A in case i), B in case ii) - presumably in term of d, r and R.

Answer (score 1):

point $A$ is the one referenced in part $i$ and point $B$ is the one referenced in part $ii$.  I would answer with the distance from the center of the smaller circle to the points of interest.  It will be a formula in terms of $d,r,R$